# How to get the user session using apache shiro with jersey RESTful

Tags: java, apache, session, shiro

Class A, I create a session using Shiro:

```
Subject currentUser = null;
currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
Session session = currentUser.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("currentUser", username);
```

Class B, I have a restful web service method that is trying to get the username session:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String currentUser = (String) session.getAttribute("currentUser");
logger.debug("currently logged in user is: " + currentUser);
```

logger shows `currentUser` as `null`

Question: 
How to get the currentUser session from my code? Is this correct? I am novice with Shiro.
Can someone help?

I have read about shiro DefaultWebSessionManager from shiro's site tutorial but cannot understand it. Can someone give me an example of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score -3):

Read all the reference doc for shiro, it isn't very long. http://shiro.apache.org/reference.html

Then look at this sample project for help with configuration and use of shiro api.

https://github.com/dominicfarr/skybird-shiro